# Type forwarding in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, return-type, decltype, trailing-return-type

Following situation:

```
class CTest
{
public:
    CTest()=default;
    ~CTest()=default;
    auto SomeFunc_Helper(std::integral_constant<int, 8> param) -> uint64_t*; //param is in reality more or less a self-implemented std::integral_constant
    auto SomeFunc() -> [how do I get the return type of SomeFunc_Helper?]
    {
        return SomeFunc_Helper(std::integral_constant<int, sizeof(uintptr_t)>{});
    }
};
```

For `SomeFunc()` I tried something like

`auto SomeFunc() ->decltype(&CTest::SomeFunc_Helper(std::integral_constant<int, 8>))` gives me the error that `std::integral_constant<int, 8>` could not be resolved.
So my question would be how one would do a type-forwarding from one function to another function?
(Solutions up to C++11 excluding the `std::` namespace are welcome)

Comment: What's the point of passing a `std::integral_constant<int, 8>` parameter? All objects of this type are identical.

Comment: `auto SomeFunc() -> uint64_t*`

Comment: @appleapple That makes the code more brittle.  Now if `SomeFunc_Helper` you have to remember to change `SomeFunc` as well.

Comment: @NathanOliver yeah, I know. But thanks for point that out. (Just don't see the need here. (and `SomeFunc` may someday needs return different type than it's helper.)

Comment: @n.m. I updated my current situation, I hope it makes it more clear (I want to have code, which does the masking of bits on 32-bit systems differently than on 64-bit systems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
auto SomeFunc() -> decltype(SomeFunc_Helper(std::integral_constant<int, 8>()))  
{
   /* ... */
}
```

The argument to `decltype` in the trailing return type can be any valid expression, in this case, the exact call to the member function that is actually performed in the function body.

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: It's expressing a certain level of uncertainty that I always feel when posting snippets that I didn't test :) Anyway, thanks to @Ron for the edit.

Comment: This ends up invoking the function twice. I'm not sure if that's what the question asker is looking for.

Comment: @AlexB `decltype` is an unevaluated context

Comment: @AlexB Are you sure `decltype` is calling the function and you are not just seeing the function called in the return statement?

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the cases where a macro is worthwhile.

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }
```

now you can just:

```
auto SomeFunc()
RETURNS( SomeFunc_Helper(std::integral_constant<int, sizeof(uintptr_t)>{}) )
```

There has been a proposal that `RETURNS` equivalent functionality will become `=>` or somesuch in lambdas; I hope it will be generalized.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [`std::result_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of), however, in this case, you should be fine with only declaring the return type as `decltype(auto)` (since C++14):

```
auto SomeFunc() -> decltype(auto)
{
    return SomeFunc_Helper(std::integral_constant<int, 8>{});
}
```

This way, if the function returns a reference, for example, you perfectly forward the reference to the `SomeFunction`, too.

Comment: `decltype(auto)` is a C++14 construct.  This Q is tagged as C++11

Comment: this solution would be great, but as @NathanOliver has written I am allowed to use features upto C++11 (only the core-language without std::)

Comment: @mbed_dev So you cannot even use `std::result_of`?

Comment: @ProXicT unfortunately not :(

Comment: @mbed_dev Ok, I will keep this solution here anyway, maybe it will be helpful for someone else who might stumble across this :-)

Comment: Thank you very much, it's helpful anyway